# Spring-integration - MulticastReceivingChannelAdapter - choose specific NIC from multiple (UDP)

Tags: spring-integration

I am looking code snippet with java configuration for MulticastReceivingChannelAdapter and MulticastSendingMessageHandler using spring-integration and spring boot.The requirement is multicast socket should be bind with specific Port and specific NIC.

Answer (score 0):

See [the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#ip-endpoint-reference).

Specifically, table 12 (at the time of writing)...

**local-address** On a multi-homed system, specifies an IP address for the interface to which the socket is bound.

So, just set that property (`localAddress` when using Java configuration).

This is how it's used...

```
            String localAddress = getLocalAddress();
            if (localAddress != null) {
                InetAddress whichNic = InetAddress.getByName(localAddress);
                socket.setInterface(whichNic);
            }
```

The port is passed into the contstructor.